# How to track a users flow through your app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a RoR app with 3 pages.
The user can get to page 3 via a button on page 1 or page 2.
On page 3, how can I track where they came from - so I can send them back to that page?

Thanks

Comment: What are the urls of the 3 pages? I don't need the domain, how are the paths structured? For example `localhost:3000/pages/1` `localhost:3000/pages/3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are three solutions.

First, store the previous page url in the session. See: [How to save http referer in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341879/how-to-save-http-referer-in-rails)

Second, store the url in `params` of get request. For example, the button will on page 1 look like this: `link_to "page 3", "/page3", :ref => "page1"`

And third, use http referer already answered by @johnernaut

Comment: http referer isn't provided by all browsers: use it at your own risks

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use `request.referer` to send the user back from any page they arrived on.

`<%= link_to "Back", request.referer %>`